# 4-to-10 Decoder truth table

Tags: digital-logic

I was given in a lab a 4-to-10 decoder truth table. I was wondering why it stops at 10 inputs. However, my circuit could hold up to 15 instructions.

So for instance, I built my circuit and it went from 0000 --> 1111. I have a picture of the circuit, however I don't know if it is useful to post it along this question. I'll edit with it if need be!

Comment: Might be to convert binary to decimal ( 0 - 9 )

Comment: I don't think so. Plus I'm not sure if I got it correctly but, aren't decoders used for  finding the address in the ram? Also, this is the quote from my text but my question is related to the statement so it doesn't really help me : "The 7442 decoder is a 4 input, 10 output active low decoder. For any input greater than 9 or 10012, the
value across all outputs will be a logic 1 since there are no outputs corresponding with any inputs
greater than 9. The truth table for the 7442 is shown below in Table 4.
"

Comment: Nope. Decoders are used to 'Decode the input', speaking loosely. You can even realise logic functions using decoders and some additional gates. Finding address is just one of uncountable applications of decoders. See here and links on this page for more -> http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/combination/comb_5.html

Answer (score 1):

If there is four input variables it is possible to make 16 different combination. That means 4:16 decoder is also possible. But that doesn't mean when ever at input side there is four variables there should be 16 outputs.

Decoders are designed based on the application requirement. If number of output possibilities is in between 9 to 16 we have to go for 4 input variables.

For example if we want to make a BCD decoder, there is only 10 possible output combination. In that case we will use four variable at the input side. Here input combinations 1010, 1011, 1100, 1101, 1110, 1111 is unused.